Ubuntu 22.04 only boot via Generic/Recovery mode
I have a dual boot system. Win10 + Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
And after some update (can´t be sure which one) I'm unable to boot from the default Ubuntu grub option.
If I try, it only gets BLACK SCREEN and nothing happens until I manually press the restart physical button.
But if I go to Advanced Ubuntu Options or something like that, from grub. I mange to boot and log in normally (sometimes it doesnt work).
Already tried to uninstall and reinstall nvidia graphics drivers, but I cant make it work.
some information:
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic                   6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic                   6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic                   6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic                   6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic                   6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-15-generic                   6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-17-generic                   6.5.0-17.17~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-18-generic                   6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-21-generic                   6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-25-generic                   6.5.0-25.25~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic                   6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-27-generic                   6.5.0-27.28~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-28-generic                   6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-35-generic                   6.5.0-35.35~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-41-generic                   6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-44-generic                   6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.5.0-45-generic                   6.5.0-45.45~22.04.1                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic                   6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04                  6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3                               amd64        Generic Linux kernel image


$ sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.8.0-40-generic-advanced-bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic root=UUID=bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce ro  nomodeset
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-40-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.8.0-40-generic-advanced-bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.8.0-40-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic root=UUID=bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce ro  nomodeset
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-40-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.8.0-40-generic-recovery-bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.8.0-40-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic root=UUID=bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-45-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.5.0-45-generic-advanced-bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.5.0-45-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-45-generic root=UUID=bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce ro  nomodeset
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-45-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-45-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.5.0-45-generic-recovery-bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.5.0-45-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-45-generic root=UUID=bf1ec990-de00-43b8-ba09-f2e7b7bdebce ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-45-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

Nvidia driver seems to be mixed up different versions:
$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia 
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-535:amd64                       535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-535                           535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:amd64                    535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:i386                     535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-545:amd64                    545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                        amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-550:amd64                    550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                        amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-535:amd64                     535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-535:i386                      535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-535:amd64                     535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-535:i386                      535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-535:amd64                      535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-535:amd64                       535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386                        535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-535:amd64                         535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-535:i386                          535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-26-generic      6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1+2                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-26
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-36-generic      6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-36
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-37-generic      6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1                               amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-37
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic      6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-39
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-14-generic      6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1+5                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-14
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-15-generic      6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-15
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-17-generic      6.5.0-17.17~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-17
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-18-generic      6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1                               amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-18
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-21-generic      6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-21
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-25-generic      6.5.0-25.25~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-25
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-26-generic      6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1                               amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-26
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-27-generic      6.5.0-27.28~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-27
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-28-generic      6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-35-generic      6.5.0-35.35~22.04.1                               amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-35
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-41-generic      6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-41
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-44-generic      6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-44
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.8.0-40-generic      6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3                               amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.8.0-40
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04     6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3                               amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-535 for the generic-hwe-22.04 flavour
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-26-generic      6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1+2                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-26 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-36-generic      6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-36 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-37-generic      6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1                               amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-37 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic      6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-39 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-14-generic      6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1+5                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-14 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-15-generic      6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-15 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-17-generic      6.5.0-17.17~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-17 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-18-generic      6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1                               amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-18 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-21-generic      6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-21 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-25-generic      6.5.0-25.25~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-25 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-26-generic      6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1                               amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-26 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-27-generic      6.5.0-27.28~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-27 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-28-generic      6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-35-generic      6.5.0-35.35~22.04.1                               amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-35 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-41-generic      6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-41 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-44-generic      6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1+1                             amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-44 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-45-generic      6.5.0-45.45~22.04.1                               amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-45 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.8.0-40-generic      6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3                               amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.8.0-40 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-6.5.0-45-generic       6.5.0-45.45~22.04.1                               amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-45-generic
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-6.8.0-40-generic       6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3                               amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 6.8.0-40-generic
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-535                       535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-545                       545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                        amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-dkms-545-open                           545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                        amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package (open kernel module)
ii  nvidia-driver-535                              535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-firmware-535-535.183.01                 535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        Firmware files used by the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-535                       535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-545                       545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                        amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-535                       535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                                   0.8.17.1                                          all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                510.47.03-0ubuntu1                                amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-535                               535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                        0.18.2                                            all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535                  535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver


If I open Nvidia app, it is using v535.183.01. Tried to change this on Software & Update application, but didnt work.

Also tried to manually download and install NVIDIA DRIVER ./executable.run but it failed. Installed gcc-12 and keeps failing.
I want to find a solution that is not completely format the OS. What else can I try?

I had a similar problem.
Running
apt install nvidia-driver-550
solved it for me

That will not work as an answer. Before installing a new driver the old one needs to be completely removed. You need the steps for that to make that an answer.
